# name 'CustomBusinessDay' is not defined

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have imported the pandas.tseries.holiday library.

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import *
```

Called the function USFederalHolidayCalendar

```
cal = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
```

And then I am trying to call CustomBusinessDay, it gives me error :

```
cbd = CustomBusinessDay(holidays=cal.holidays())
NameError: name 'CustomBusinessDay' is not defined
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: if CustomBusinessDay() is a method of USFederalHolidayCalendar(), then you should type cal.CustomBusinessDay(holidays=cal.holidays())

Comment: you forgot: `from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay`

Comment: Ohh, didnt know, I needed to import it separately.

Thanks a lot !!